# Removing index.php from url using .htaccess even if the user requests it

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I never want index.php to show up in my URL, even if the user inputs it. Is this possible?

This is variation whatever after several tries. I've come close a few times but this is where it's at for now.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /sub-dir/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$  //If URL ends in index.php
RewriteRule (.*)index\.php $1  //Somehow remove index.php from the url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Currently I have permalink set up where if the user enters domain.com/sub-dir/my-perma-lin/ it generates a string on the page based on my-perma-link to look like My Perma Link. What I'd like is if the user submits any URL ending in index.php it just removes that from the URL but leaves everything else as is.

domain.com/sub-dir/index.php --> domain.com/sub-dir/
domain.com/sub-dir/my-perma-link/index.php --> domain.com/sub-dir/my-perma-link

I've written quite a few rules in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ that work perfectly but when I upload it (to Dreamhost) nothing works.

This for example should work according to the the tester

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /sub-dir/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php  //Not needed but thought it would/should help
RewriteRule (.*)(index\.php)+ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But it just removes everything after /sub-dir/

I'm either missing something super obvious or it's not possible ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some flags to your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /sub-dir/  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(\?|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You can ditch the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$` condition, as that's being checked by the regex in the `RewriteRule`. You need to include a `$` at the end of the regex, and include the flags `L` to stop rewriting and `R=301` to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this moves everything from the url. domain.com/sub-dir/pema-link also just becomes domain.com/sub-dir/. That's why I had originally put in the condition, even though that doesn't seem to prevent the behavior now.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen I see what you mean now, I've changed the answer to match against the request itself, so that it won't match the `index.php` that is being internally rewritten by the last rule.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's perfect. If you have a moment I'd really appreciate if you could explain line three. Why are you looking for 3-9 characters of A-Z? Why are there three pieces to that line?

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of an HTTP request, which looks something like: `GET /some/path HTTP/1.1`. The `[A-Z]{3,9}` matches the "method" (GET, POST, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS, etc), and the next bit matches the `/some/path`, which needs to start with a `/` and end with `index.php`. The `(\?|\ )` part at the end ensures we're matching the end of the path because it's either a space or a query string.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the extra explanation